# How can I efficiently calculate the normal of a closed loop defined by coplanar points?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, plane, cross-product

We have set of coplanar points that define a closed loop, which are Counter clock wise wound. The loop is guaranteed to not be self intersecting.

We want to calculate the normal

We have two issues.

1. For points that are close to collinear, floating point precision causes erroneous normals to be calculated using cross-product.
2. For a concave closed loop, some normals will point the opposite way.

Our solution is to calculate the normal for all sequential segments that define the closed loop. This way, issue 1 can be overcome by discarding outlying calculated normals. Issue 2 can be overcome by knowing that the direction of the majority of the normals will be correct.

This seems to work, but is very expensive.

Is there a simpler, cheaper, more elegant solution?

Comment: _Issue 2 can be overcome by knowing that the direction of the majority of the normals will be correct_ I'm not sure that your solution work. For example, imagine a geometry like this `<(` if your arc has more points that those two segments, your calculations will compute more normals that are pointing to opposite direction

Comment: That's my coarse suggestion: First calculated a maximum dot product between two vectors that lead to an acceptable error in cross product calculation. Now, on your geometry, keep a point fixed and use the other points to calculate the associated vector (p_x - p_fixed = vector_x). Keep one vector fixed and calculated dot product with the others vectors. When you find a dot that is less than your minimum acceptable, calculated the cross product. Or just keep doing dot product until you find the better one. For that, you perform your vector product calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming points `{p_i}`, `0<=i<n`, forms a counterclockwise polygon, compute the sum of the cross product of every triangle of a triangle fan of the polygon (even in the concave parts):

```
normal = vector3(0, 0, 0);
for(int i=1; i<n-1; ++i) 
    normal += cross(p[i+1]-p[0],p[i]-p[0]);
normal /= norm(n);
```

This is derived from the [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). The length of the normal (before normalization) is equal to two times the signed area enclosed by the loop. So you are guaranteed that it will not be null (if the area is not null) and you are guaranteed that it will point in the right direction.

Comment: What about erroneous cross-product results potentially skewing the final normal sum?

Comment: @lfgtm What do you mean by erroneous? If you mean that some triangle will be inverted and the cross product will be pointing on the other side, there is nothing to worry. This formula works for concave polygon too. They will contribute as a negative area, but will be compensated overall.